# How to get client ip address aws elb?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am using aws elb for load balancing. I need client ip address. But it gives us elb ip address. So i went to aws documentation and they told to enable Enabling Proxy Protocol. After enabling also, i am getting elb address only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read about X-Forwarded-For HTTP header:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Elastic Load Balancer supports it.

Comment: Sorry but iam using https